# Download nested JSON from URL and make Observable Object SwiftUI, ERROR: "Missing Argument for parameter 'from' in call"

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I am trying to download a nested JSON file from an URL. I want to make it Observable Object so that my App will update its view when the download is finished.
Here I have my structures and the class I have created in order to make it an Observable Object. This is also where my Error: "Missing argument in parameter 'from' in call" appears: (Thanks for any help!)

```
struct SpotDetail: Codable {
    
    var spot: String
    var day0: DayDetail
    var day1: DayDetail
    var day2: DayDetail
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case spot = "spot"
        case day0 = "day0"
        case day1 = "day1"
        case day2 = "day2"
    }
}

struct DayDetail: Codable {
    var date: String
    var wind: [Int]
    var gust: [Int]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date = "date"
        case wind = "wind"
        case gust = "gust"
        
    }
}

class networkSpotData: ObservableObject {
    let objectWillChange = ObjectWillChangePublisher()
    
    var WindSpot = SpotDetail() { // ERROR: "Missing Argument for parameter 'from' in call"
        willSet {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}
```

And the function that downloads from the URL:

```
extension ContentView {

    func loadspotdata(url: String)  {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bene2907/Bene2907.github.io/main/template.json") else {
            return
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            if let data = data {
                if let response_obj = try? JSONDecoder().decode(SpotDetail.self, from: data) {
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        spotData.WindSpot = response_obj
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }.resume()
    }
    
}
```

Finally I have my view to present the data:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var spotData = networkSpotData()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(spotData.WindSpot.spot)")
                .padding()
            
            Text("\(spotData.WindSpot.day0.date)")
                .padding()
        }.onAppear(perform: {
            loadspotdata()
        })
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use default constructor in

```
var WindSpot = SpotDetail() { // ERROR: "Missing Argument for parameter 'from' in call"
```

you have to initialize properties with default values in `SpotDetail`, like

```
struct SpotDetail: Codable {
    
    var spot: String = ""
    var day0: DayDetail = DayDetail() // this also should be initialised properties

    ...    
}
```